# Credentials of Administrator on VMware Cloud vSphere

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-vsphere

I got the Default vCenter Credentials which is Default vCenter User Account
`cloudadmin@vmc.local`.

There are a lot of configurations which only an Administrator could do such turn ON/OFF vSphere HA. I saw there is an Administrator role, but I don't know how I get the Credentials for that.

Comment: The credentials are defined during the installation of vCenter/PSC. If you need to reset the password, the [procedure is documented](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2034608).

Comment: @GeraldSchneider, well I do not have the privileges with `CloudAdminGroup` to create, modify and delete a new role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, VMware Cloud does not have Administrator access, only cloudAdmin, and CloudGlobalAdmin roles.